# Scanner class fails to take string input

Tags: java

It is a simple java code.. but Scanner class isn't taking the string as input. why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        double y=sc.nextDouble();
        String s =sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: "+s);
        System.out.println("Double: "+y);
        System.out.println("Int: "+x);
}
```

Comment: Use `String s =sc.next();` or add `sc.nextLine();` after reading `double`.

Comment: use next() for string instead of nextLine()

Comment: but whats wrong with nextLine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `sc.nextInt()` and `sc.nextDouble()` method does not consume the  newline character of your input, so that newline is consumed in the next call to `sc.nextLine()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int x=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); 
        double y=sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();
        String s =sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: "+s);
        System.out.println("Double: "+y);
        System.out.println("Int: "+x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextLine()` method to read all values and then parse them into the corresponding type (Integer, Double, etc). See why here: [Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine()) vs scanner.nextInt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586489/integer-parseintscanner-nextline-vs-scanner-nextint)

Comment: But why does it fail to take input as string?

Comment: Because of the newline that remains in the input buffer.